# Getting "prefix 'soap' is not defined" in xslt file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform a string with xml data (response from a web service). I tried to start simple by just getting the name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ABRSearchByABNResponse/ABRPayloadSearchResults/response/legalName/">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="givenName"/>
            </td>      
          </tr>   
      </xsl:for-each>

      </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I get "prefix 'soap' is not defined", how do I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and complete solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XSLT any namespace prefix used in an XPath expression must be defined in a corresponding namespace declaration.

This is not the case with your code and hence the error.

**Solution**:

Declare the soap namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
 xmlns:soap="http://soap/envelope/"
>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: Yep, I am a little bit sleepy this morning. :)

Answer (score 0):

The namespace prefix, `soap` in your case, is just shorthand for the real namespace URI. To avoid you have `http://soap/envelope/` everywhere, you can define once that `soap` stands for `http://soap/envelope/`, and use `soap` in the rest of your document.

This means that if you use a namespace prefix, it has to be defined so that the real namespace can be found.

You could also declare that `pizza` corresponds to `http://soap/envelope/` and use that instead. The `soap` namespace prefix is not special.

Comment: So i Should use <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:soap="http://soap/Envelope/Body/"> and then         <xsl:for-each select="soap/ABRSearchByABNResponse/ABRPayloadSearchResults/response/legalName">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="givenName"/>
            </td>      
          </tr>   
      </xsl:for-each> ?